# What if values of members of MIB_IF_ROW2 structure exceeds the limit?

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, interface

It is just a question out of curiosity. Windows function `GetIfEntry2` returns the output in a  `MIB_IF_ROW2` structure. Some members of the structure like `InOctets`,`OutOctets`,etc are of type `ULONG64`. [This microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230392.aspx) tells that max limit of `ULONG64` is `18446744073709551615`. Since these `InOctets`, `OutOctets` etc goes on increasing, what happens if the value exceeds the limit? Will it return or fail?

Comment: If the API has specifically been written to deal with it, it might possibly return an error, but I suspect it would just wrap to 0. The chances of anyone ever encountering the phenomenon are slim since it would involve transferring 16 exbibytes of data through the one interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would never happen. That many bytes is equal to ~17179869184 GiB, and to transfer that much data, you'd need to send or receive one full gigabyte per second for more than 540 years.

But if that did somehow happen, the overflow behavior would depend entirely on the network driver, since that's what reports the data (according to [this NDIS summary](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Internals_of_NDIS_driver_for_VirtIO_based_network_adapter#Statistics)). More than likely, it would just flip over to zero and start counting again. `GetIfEntry2` just gives you whatever data it receives from the driver.